# Как правильно настроить сайт на express.js на docker с nginx?

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose

Всем привет, подскажите, в чём ошибка, я пытаюсь настроить проект на express.js, пытаюсь развернуть на docker'e, не могу подключить nginx, сайт не запускается вообще, вот docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  backend:
    container_name: my-server
    image: my-server:0.2
    build: 
      context: .
    ports:
      - "80:5001"
    environment:
      - EXTERNAL_PORT=5001
    depends_on:
      - node_db
      
  node_db:
    container_name: my_db
    image: "postgres:13.5"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - nps_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=name
      - DB_USER=admin
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_HOST=my_db
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19
    volumes:
      - .\nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - backend

volumes:
  nps_data: {}
```

На самом докере сайт поднялся, но на моем ip сайта нет.
default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name 44.11.22.33 www.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://backend:5001;
    }
}
```

Comment: Выглядит норм. 1. `сайт не запускается вообще` - какая ошибка? 502? 2. Также приложите `docker-compose ps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порт 80 пытаются занять оба сервиса nginx и backend.
Фронтом я так понимаю должен быть nginx и он должен слушать 80 и 443 порты.
Сервис backend на то и бэкенд, чтобы не быть доступным извне. Поэтому порт 80 не нужно пробрасывать в него.

Таким образом проблема с портами будет решена.

Далее возникнет проблема с https. У вас сервис nginx слушает 80 и 443 порты, конфиг только для 80 порта. Т.е. приложение не будет доступно по https.
Надо добавить в default.conf директивы listen 443 и сертификаты.